# How to combine two PDF using excel vba using Bluebeam Revu 21

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried with Bluebeam to combine two PDF programmatically in **Excel VBA**. But I have facing issue like "ActiveX component cannot create object"

```
    Dim BluebeamApp As Object
    Dim PDFDocument As Object
    Dim PDFPath1 As String
    Dim PDFPath2 As String

    ' Define the paths to the PDF files you want to combine
    PDFPath1 = "D:\Keylock\keylayout1.pdf"
    PDFPath2 = "D:\Keylock\keylayout1.pdf"

    ' Create a Bluebeam Application object
    Set BluebeamApp = CreateObject("RevuLauncher.Application")

    ' Create a new PDFDocument object
    Set PDFDocument = BluebeamApp.NewDocument

    ' Insert the first PDF file
    PDFDocument.InsertPages PDFPath1, 0, 0, 0, ""

    ' Insert the second PDF file after the first one
    PDFDocument.InsertPages PDFPath2, 1, 0, 0, ""

    ' Save the combined PDF to a new file
    PDFDocument.SaveAs "D:\Keylock\CombinedFile.pdf", False

    ' Close the PDF document
    PDFDocument.Close

    ' Release the Bluebeam objects
    Set PDFDocument = Nothing
    Set BluebeamApp = Nothing`
```

Error image:

[image]

What is missing in this code? Which library must be include for above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine pdf using ghostscript

````
    Dim inputPDFs As String
    Dim outputPDF As String
    Dim command As String

    ' Set the path to Ghostscript executable
    ghostscriptPath = "C:\Program Files\gs\gs10.01.2\bin\gswin64c.exe"

    ' Set paths for input PDFs and the merged PDF
    inputPDFs = """D:\Keylock\Template2.pdf"" ""D:\Keylock\Template3.pdf"""
    outputPDF = "D:\Keylock\merged.pdf"

    ' Build the Ghostscript command
    command = ghostscriptPath & " -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=" & outputPDF & " " & inputPDFs

    ' Execute the Ghostscript command
    Shell command, vbNormalFocus```
````